# Union of two 'not-connected' sets of real numbers

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

If $P$ and $Q$ are two 'not-connected' subsets of the set of all real number then is the union of $P$ and $Q$ not connected?

I haven't found any counterexample yet but the answer is given 'no'.someone please provide a counterexample.

Comment: Have you counted your marks in JAM ?

Comment: Yes.Its 40.33.what is yours?

Comment: What do you think about what would be the estimated score to secure 250 rank this year?

Comment: I think , paper was very lengthy this year as I couldn't attempt  8 NATs of 2 marks and 4 MSQs, So probably we need 36 marks to get any IITs and approx. 40 marks for under 250.

Comment: Yes I do think so.

Answer (score 1):

How about $P$ being the set of rationals, and $Q$ the set of irrationals?

Or $P=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ and $Q=[1,2]\cup[3,4]$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following fact:

> In $\mathbb{R}$, the complement of a disconnected set with at least $3$ [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) is also disconnected.

This enables you to construct many counterexamples, including every possible case with $P \cap Q = \emptyset$.  Simply let $P$ be any disconnected set with at least $3$ "gaps", and let $Q = \mathbb{R} \setminus P$.  These are disconnected, yet $P \cup Q = \mathbb{R}$ is connected.  Of course this process can also be carried out on any connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider the set of rational number and the set of irrational numbers.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much Siong.